# PySerial. Read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data

Tags: python, windows-7, embedded-linux, pyserial, python-3.6

I have a windows 7 os pc, using pyserial in python3.6 to talk to an embedded board with a debian Jessie os that is using pyserial python 3.6 to listen. The cable between the two is a USB to UART bridge controller from a microUSB port on the board to a USB port on the pc. These are my scripts:

PC:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5')
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.bytesize = 8
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.stopbits = 1

data = bytearray(b'A')
No = ser.write(data)

ser.close()
```

BOARD:

```
import serial

ComPort = serial.Serial('dev/ttyS0')
ComPort.baudrate = 115200
ComPort.bytesize = 8
ComPort.parity = 'N'
ComPort.stopbits = 1

data = ComPort.read(1)
print(data)

ComPort.close()
```

THE PROBLEM:
I run the script on the board first, it will run and wait without incident until I run the script on the pc.  Once I run the pc script, it takes a second or two for the error in the title to pop up on the board and stop the script.  There are no errors on the pc side, and the script runs and finishes in less than a second.

I am connected to the board via putty ssh on the pc.  I need to be able to send commands and files between these two via this serial connection.  Any help or working examples would be a great help.  Is there a problem with using pyserial on both the sender and receiver?

Comment: Can you show the error message you are receiving?

Comment: Also, are you not looping the read on the board to wait for input?

Comment: `While True:
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    ser.read(bytesToRead)`

Comment: @EastonBornemeier he doesn't need to loop for this. it's set to never time out, and will wait on `ComPort.read(1)` until 1 byte is received. For this test, there is not need to read in a loop

Comment: *"from a microUSB port on the board"* -- And yet you're reading from `/dev/ttyS0`??? Perform a sanity test on the Debian side (aka the *"board"*): instead of your script, use a terminal emulator program, such as **minicom**, (or `cat </dev/ttyS0` if necessary) to verify that the board is actually receiving something.  IOW you're probably using the wrong device node.